# How to load .jsp file dynamically in particular div of same jsp while clicking jquery tabs

Tags: jquery

I have a one contain.jsp in that i used the jquery tabs when i select particular tab then i want to load a jsp file in particular div in contain.jsp which has to be out side the tabs panel.

can any one please help me to do this.

Comment: How about using IFrame?

Comment: use jQuery's load() to fetch jsp and display inside div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code to load content of a jsp into a particular div with id mydiv, when tab with id tabToClick is clicked:

```
$('#tabToClick').on('click', function() {
   $('#mydiv').load('mypage.jsp');
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Getting a [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found] error. Changed jsp path to WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/mypage.jsp but still getting the same error. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: It has to be your full context path or relative context path. In spring I use ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/. I don't know if its a generic thing.